# Designing schmitt trigger having two positive thresholds

Tags: comparator, schmitt-trigger

I have two supplies, V1 and V2. V1 is fix to a certain voltage. V2 is variable and I want to switch the external circuit ON when V2 < V1. For this case I have used OP-AMP as a comparator. But what I want to do next is to put two thresholds (UT and LT; **Both positive**).

The Output of OP-Amp should be either +Vsat OR Ground.
If I set V(-) at gnd then I can't set the lower threshold i.e. LT. How can i achieve this?

Here is the poor screenshot to give you an idea.
[image]

Edited: To correct the labels

Comment: it would be a lot clearer to use the same terminology in your text as in your diagram. Also add a schematic for what you have so far that works. I don't see any problem with setting a lower threshold, but you do, which means I can't guess what constraints you are thinking with at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Schmitt trigger circuit makes it difficult to apply variable upper and lower threshold voltages that are independent of each other so, start by creating two threshold voltages using independent resistive potential dividers.

Next use two comparators both fed with the common input signal but whose reference voltages are from one or the other threshold voltages. Finally, use a D type flip-flop where the upper threshold comparator feeds the clock pin and the lower threshold comparator feeds the reset pin. The D pin is fed with logical 1. Output is taken from the nQ output of the flip-flop.

This works because I've used it and is pretty similar to what happens inside a 555 timer: -

[image]

If you had access to the non-inverting pin of comparator 2 then you could use a 555 chip; trigger and threshold would be tied together and connected to the input. Upper voltage threshold would connect to "control voltage" and lower threshold would connect to comparator two's non-inverting input.